# RMS of HD-EMG Signals Processing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I want to extract the RMS values of the EMG from and electrode array that contains 64 channels (HD-EMG,OTbioelettronica). I'm supposed make the single differencial first , then Rectify the Signal and then take the RMS values I'm new to matlab so I don't know very much about signal processing any info will be helfull. This is where I have come so far:

** I transposed the signal because it's easier to have the 64 channels in rows and the time points in columns (I had a 403250x64 cell array and I reversed it).

%% Allow the user to select the MATLAB file(s)
[Filename, Pathname] = uigetfile({'*.mat'}, 'Select the file', 'MultiSelect', 'on');

%% Check if the user selected multiple files
if iscell(Filename)
% Loop through each selected file
for i = 1:length(Filename)
% Import the file
fileToRead = fullfile(Pathname, Filename{i});
loadedData = load(fileToRead);

```
    % Extract the cell array (assuming the variable name is 'Data')
    Data = loadedData.Data;
    
    % Transpose the cell array
    reversed_data = cellfun(@transpose, Data, 'UniformOutput', false);
    
    % Proceed with further processing using the transposed cell array 'reversed_data'
    % For example, you can save the transposed data to a new file, or perform additional analysis
    
    % Display a message indicating the completion of processing for the current file
 end
```

else
% Import the single selected file
fileToRead = fullfile(Pathname, Filename);
loadedData = load(fileToRead);

```
% Extract the cell array (assuming the variable name is 'Data')
Data = loadedData.Data;

% Transpose the cell array
reversed_data = cellfun(@transpose, Data, 'UniformOutput', false);

% Proceed with further processing using the transposed cell array 'reversed_data'
% For example, you can save the transposed data to a new file, or perform additional analysis
```

end